# site redirecting to core/install.php after migration

Tags: 8

I have migrated my site to different server and I am redirected to install.php page.

Here is the steps I have done:

1. zip whole site and extract it in new server.
2. export database and import it to new database (using phpmyadmin)
3. modify database credential in site/defaults/setting.php

any idea why drupal redirects to install page?

Comment: It redirects if it can't find a valid DB connection, or the data it's expecting in the database once it has connected

Comment: the DB connection is valid. i had tested it

Comment: **the data it's expecting in the database once it has connected** i didn't get what you mean

Comment: If the tables are wrongly named, for example, or they don't have the right data in them. You can follow the logic yourself from `DrupalKernel::handle()`. You need to determine why `Database::getConnectionInfo()` or `drupal_installation_attempted()` are returning falsey values

Comment: how the table can be wrongly when I am export it from one db and import it in another. By the way both `Database::getConnectionInfo()`, `drupal_installation_attempted()` not false

Comment: Also see `InstallerRedirectTrait::shouldRedirectToInstaller`. I can't debug this from here, sorry, you'll have to step through it yourself

Comment: @Clive thanks for directing. I was doing some debugging before I post my issue here. I am questioning here in hope to find some guidance on what could be the reason of redirecting to installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue today (my site kept redirecting to install.php after migration to new host) and spent half-a-day troubleshooting.
The db connection was OK. I double-checked that the db-name, db-user, and db-user-pass are correct in the site/defaults/setting.php
In the end, it turned out that when I exported the database from my previous hosting, the names of the tables were prepended with a prefix. After importing the tables in the new database, I didn't specify the prefix in the settings.php file. Therefore, drupal was not able to locate the correct tables, because it looked for the *users* table but in the db, that table was actually named *prefix_users* and so on.

$databases['default']['default'] = array (
'database' => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
**'prefix' => '!!!',**
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '',
'namespace' => 'Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql',
'driver' => 'mysql',
);

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's file permission problem. Try to set the owner of the web-root of Drupal installation:

```
chown -R YOUR-USER:WEBSERVER-USER .
```

Especially it's file permission problem of the settings.php. If your web server can't read this file, the new install process is started and redirects to /core/install.php

If it helps so you can go on with more secure file permission setting described here: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924